# Why is my responsive navbar isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started building my own website, by adding the background and the navbar and immediately wanted to make it responsive!
After doing it, the navbar is working perfectly, etc, but then when I try the responsive.. it's not working at all, I mean as the buttons disappear, the animation isn't working anymore.

Comment: Hi man, welcome to SO!, when we ask questions here we tend to give some code and share some of the attemps we have done to solve our issue, may I have the code you generated edited into your question? and also, if you have made any attempts to fix it, please edit them into your question. Cheers!

Comment: Bonjour! 

With no code to look at, it's impossible to say where things have gone awry. 

‍♀️

Comment: One thing I would like to point out is that websites are responsive by default. The only design problems we have are the ones we create for ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

Btw you can attach examples of code for better experience. 
So you need to set eyes on:

Media queries - use it for css style at resolution breakpoints:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media

As variant you can use flexbox markup: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Hope it help